# C++ Substract the end of a string, not knowing length of the result

Tags: c++

I have a string like this: 001,"John Marvin","doctor", "full time"
I want to delete everything after (001) with substr, but, the length of (001) is not always 3 so I can not put something like thie:

```
string chain = "001,\"John Marvin\",\"doctor\", \"full time\"";
```

`std::string partial = chain.substr(0,3);`

How can I proceed in this case?

Comment: [OT] you might considered use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) so `"001,\"John Marvin\",\"doctor\", \"full time\""` becomes `R"001,"John Marvin","doctor", "full time""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the index of the first comma and use that to determine where to cut off the string.

Something like:

```
string chain = "001,\"John Marvin\",\"doctor\", \"full time\"";
int cutoff = chain.find(',');
string newString = chain.substr(0, cutoff);
```

Tested [here](http://cpp.sh/9l6k).

Comment: Thank you, I have my answer now :)